# Devexpress - Xtragrid : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

Let me sketch the situation first:
We have an application that monitors file-transfers from & to a fileserver. When the user transfers a/multiple file(s) then the result of the copy is shown in a overview where a **Xtragrid-Gridcontrol** shows all the files and if the copy was successfull or not.

When de copy was **not succesfull** then a combobox is shown to choose the desired action (ignore,retry, link,...). This combobox is set using the event `CustomRowCellEdit`

Code example from that CustomRowCellEdit:

```
        Dim myCb As RepositoryItemLookUpEdit = New RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
        myCb.DataSource = GenerateActionlistForDoubleFolder()
        myCb.NullValuePrompt = Documentum.Common.Tools.Translate(Tools.Config(m_Docbase), "[SELECT_ACTION]")
        myCb.NullText = Documentum.Common.Tools.Translate(Tools.Config(m_Docbase), "[SELECT_ACTION]")
        e.RepositoryItem = myCb
```

**The problem:**

Larger and larger quatities of files are being copied. the quatities are sometimes that big that the `Xtragrid-Gridcontrol` is often still loading when the form is shown (although the datasource has already been set).If the user interacts **too soon** with xtragrid-gridcontrol (while its still loading) then we get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception of the `Xtragrid`. (Due to the datasource of the visual component still changing)

**The needed solution:**

We should prevent the user to interact with grid while its still loading (seems obivious).

**Not working solutions:**

The event `DataSourceChanged` is being fired when you set the datasource. **Not** when all rows are loaded.

Simple enabling/disabling the grid everytime the event `CustomRowCellEdit` is fired -> Massive performanceloss

**Question:**
Has anyone encoutered this problem aswell? Is there a fullproof way to detect whether an Xtragrid has completely loaded its datasource (and visualized it)? Or is there a workaround where i don't need to use the `CustomRowCellEdit` anymore?
(Solutions from other types of grids are welcome aswell)

Thank you all for your time

**Note:** Don't ask for more code. The problem doesn't lie in the code, it lies in my  usage of the `Gridcontrol-Events`

**Documentation:** [RowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic)

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem description, but I recall some kind of problem I once had with XtraGrid that was cured by using GridControl.ForceInitialize. See here for exmple:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ForceInitializetopic

Comment: Apparently you understood it quite well. The solution you offered refers to the same area of problems. Yet this did not solve this specfic problem. But it did however solve a bug in another application of mine. Therefor: Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this sometimes in my applications as well. I primarily bind my grids to `DataTable`s, and the solution that I've found to work the best is, while your data is loading, to set your `gridControl.DataSource` to `null/Nothing` and call `Application.DoEvents()`. Once the underlying datasource is filled, set the `DataSource` back to the source.

The goal of this is to achieve a deterministic way of telling when your data is loaded. Here's a basic example implementation.

```
myGrid.DataSource = Nothing
Application.DoEvents
FillDataTableWithLoadsOfRows(myDataTable)
myGrid.DataSource = myDataTable
' ...
'Whatever actions to do that require the data to be in the grid
' ...
```

Comment: Ingenious! This solved the problem for me! Right now no more exceptions/troubles with the help of 2 lines of code! Thanks mate!